# How to do a linear regression in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, linear-regression

In a regression `Y=aX+b`, `regr_intercept(Y, X)` equals "b" and r`regr_slope(Y, X)` equals "a"?

Comment: Yes. Intercept is `b` and slope is `a`. You supply the `Y` and `X` columns. This returns an aggregated result. For fun you can do `SELECT 'Y=' || regr_slope(col1, col2) || 'X+' || regr_intercept(col1, col2) || ' is the regression formula with R-squared value of ' || regr_r2(col1, col2) AS  regression_formula_output FROM yourtable;`

Comment: i'm not sure what the problem is here

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have not supplied much details but here you go.

### Regression

A regression line is simply a line
`y = ax + b`
that is able to compute an output variable `y` for an input variable `x`. A line can be described by two parameters, also called coefficients:

- the slope `a`
- the intercept `b`

### Finding Slope & Intercept

Suppose you have two numeric columns, Y and X populated with the desired X and Y

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
 id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 X integer NOT NULL,
 Y integer NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (0,10,3);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,20,5);
```

You can find slope as follows.

```
SELECT regr_slope(y, x) slope FROM foo;
SELECT regr_intercept(y, x) intercept FROM foo;
```

**Results of query:**

slope: 0.2

intercept: 1

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9e947/6)

Comment: how do you apply the slope and intercept to your columns afterwards?

Comment: You could do

`WITH query_1 AS (
  SELECT 
    regr_slope(y, x) AS slope,
    regr_intercept(y, x) AS intercept
  FROM foo
)
SELECT
  foo.x,
  foo.y,
  query_1.slope * foo.x + query_1.intercept AS regression_line
FROM  foo, query_1`